# How to get size of data that haven't been written to disk yet?

Tags: cache, disk

In some programs percentage of copying large files get to 100% very fast and then I'm waiting much more before it goes next step.

It's caused by buffer. How to I see amount of data that are going to be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term for that is "dirty" data (data that has been changed, but not yet flushed to permanent storage).

On Linux you can find this from `/proc/meminfo` under `Dirty`:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Dirty
Dirty:               0 kB
```

Answer (score 2):

For interactive CLI view on Linux I would recommend `dstat`.